# Binding a variable in react to a function changes it to an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started learning react and working on a simple application. I am stuck in a position where i need to pass a state stored variable to a function from render. When i try to bind this to the function, the variable is changed to an Object, which i am unable to access.

Is there any way i can handle this?

My code looks like:

```
handleQuantityChange: function(e) {
  this.setState({ value: parseInt(e.target.value) });
},

handleBuy: function(bidPrice){
  console.log(bidPrice);
},

render: function(){
  this.state.bidPrice = 24;
  return <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" onChange={this.handleQuantityChange}/>
            <li>{this.state.bidPrice}</li>
            <input type="button" value="Buy" onClick={this.handleBuy.bind(this.state.bidPrice)}/>
         </form>
```

My original code is getting very complex so i didn't post that here. But for reference, please checkout this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49587/)

The code doesn't work in fiddle as this has many other issues and lack error handling that i need to work on, but it should work on a local server.
Should i approach this in a different way? Is there any better event than onChange that i could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [getInitialState](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html) fn to initialize values

```
 getInitialState: function() {
    return { bidPrice: 24 };
 },
```

and use

```
onClick={this.handleBuy.bind(this, this.state.bidPrice)}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
onClick={this.handleBuy.bind(this, this.state.bidPrice)}
```

Here is the `bind` syntax for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind.

> fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])